# vb.net linq list of object

Tags: vb.net, linq

In vb.net, using linq, join 2 list of object.
Both list are the same type.

I search the best way to concat both list grouping by Id.
Like a Distinct.

Sample :

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Reflection

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim list1 As New List(Of Item)
        For i As Integer = 1 To 4
            list1.Add(New Item(i, i.ToString))
        Next

        Dim list2 As New List(Of Item)
        For i As Integer = 3 To 6
            list2.Add(New Item(i, i.ToString))
        Next

        Dim list3 As New List(Of Item)
        list3 = (list1.Concat(list2)).ToList
        Console.WriteLine(Item.PrintList(list3).ToString)        

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module

Class Item
    Private _Id As Integer
    Private _Value As String

    Public Property Id() As Integer
        Get
            Return _Id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Id = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Value() As String
        Get
            Return _Value
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Value = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal value As String)
        Me.Id = id
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Dim sb = New Text.StringBuilder()        
        For Each item In [GetType]().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
            sb.Append(String.Format("[{0} = {1}] ", item.Name, item.GetValue(Me)))
        Next
        Return sb.ToString()
    End Function

    Public Shared Function PrintList(ByVal myList As List(Of Item)) As StringBuilder
        Dim result As New StringBuilder
        For Each i In myList
            result.AppendLine(i.ToString)
        Next
        Return result
    End Function

End Class
```

What the list3 contain after concat :

```
[_Id = 1] [_Value = 1] 
[_Id = 2] [_Value = 2] 
[_Id = 3] [_Value = 3] 
[_Id = 4] [_Value = 4] 
[_Id = 3] [_Value = 3] 
[_Id = 4] [_Value = 4] 
[_Id = 5] [_Value = 5] 
[_Id = 6] [_Value = 6]
```

What we want :

```
[_Id = 1] [_Value = 1] 
[_Id = 2] [_Value = 2] 
[_Id = 3] [_Value = 3] 
[_Id = 4] [_Value = 4] 
[_Id = 5] [_Value = 5] 
[_Id = 6] [_Value = 6]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I search the best way to concat both list grouping by Id. Like a
>   Distinct.

Use [`Enumerable.Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx).

However, you need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in the class `Item` first. Then all Linq methods will use your ID:

```
Class Item
    Public Property ID As Int32

    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        If obj Is Nothing Then Return False
        If Not TypeOf obj Is Item Then Return False
        Return Id = DirectCast(obj, Item).Id
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return Id.GetHashCode()
    End Function
End Class
```

Now you can use [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) which is efficient and clear:

```
Dim list3 = list1.Union(list2).ToList
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx):

> This method **excludes duplicates** from the return set. This is different
>   behavior to the `Concat<TSource>` method, which returns all the
>   elements in the input sequences including duplicates. ...  To compare
>   a custom data type, you need to implement this interface and provide
>   your own **GetHashCode** and **Equals** methods for the type.

Comment: for people who want to know why the GetHashCode : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden

Comment: Stefan was right too. the Concat Distinct is an alternative to Union.

Comment: @forX: `GetHashCode` is like a pre-filter for `Equals`. Every hashtable(e.g. `Dictionary`,`HashSet`) that uses the hashcode to find an object will first use `GetHashCode` and then confirm equality with `Equals`. `GetHashCode` must be efficient. It is possible that `GetHashCode` returns the same number for two different objects, but every equal object must have the same hashcode. These rules and guidelines are very helpful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

With the addition of Equals and GetHashCode in Tim Schmelter answer, you now also have the possibility to use Concat and .Distinct directly on the Query:

```
Dim list3 As List(Of Item) = list1.Concat(list2).Distinct.ToList
```

or using where and distinct in the query:

```
Dim list3 As List(Of Item) = (From data In list1.Concat(list2) Where data.Value = "MyCity" Distinct).ToList
```

variation:

```
  Dim list3 As List(Of Item) = (From data In list1.Concat(list2) Where data.Value = "MyCity").Distinct.ToList
```